# Linux .Net Core receive passed in socket

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, .net-core

Is there anything providing the ability to create a socket from a file handle in .Net Core 2? The [.Net Socket APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) don't appear to offer this functionality.

This would be useful to create a systemd [socket activated](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) daemon without having to use Accept=true and spawn a new process every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this using https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.Systemd? `ServiceManager.GetListenSockets` will give you a `Socket[]` passed from systemd.

The dotnet application needs to be started as `dotnet <assembly.dll>` (no `dotnet run`) to ensure the LISTEN_PID set by systemd matches the pid of the dotnet process.